# python two ways to return from function differences

Tags: python, return

I would like to know if there are any relevant difference in functions below:

```
def function1(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return "Number " +str(n)+ " is odd."
```

and

```
def function2(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        return n
    else:
        print "Number " +str(n)+ " is odd."
        return
```

In some online course I noticed that in one task (deffinitely more complex code than that printed above, but I made it simple to show just only a concept) automated grading was returning me an error that function did not exit normally when I used design from function1 and when I changed to design from function2 I got full score. I am really intrested why I could not use function1 as correct design, maybe somebody with more than I expierence will explain a bit and show correct with short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function  if the else is executed will return `None` where in the first it will return the value of `"Number " +str(n)+ " is odd."`

So if to need to use the value in the `"Number " +str(n)+ " is odd."` should the else be reached you would not be able to, you would only see it printed.

```
In [9]: x = function1(11)

In [10]: print x
Number 11 is odd.

In [11]: x = function2(11)
Number 11 is odd.

In [12]: print x
None
```

In your course the grader was more than likely not calling the functions using `print` so to see the output you would have to `print function1(11)`,it is the same using any `ide` like pycharm etc.., just calling the function when you just have a return will not show the return value.

Without seeing the *more complex* code there are too many possibilities but one certain part of just printing is your function will return `None` which may well be required as a value elsewhere for code to terminate.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know why it was preferred solution in course. For me more natural was first function design.

Comment: The first design _is_ better. Something weird is going on with the grader if it prefers the second.

Comment: @Kevin, yes the first design is the only way I would right it but obviously however the code is graded the output had to be printed. It would not be the only online grader I have seen that uses strange techniques

Comment: It possible that the output from the function was used elsewhere and that it was desirable in that (unknown) context to not return a string. In that case function2 is preferred.